# why this two items have different width in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

Hey guys I am learning textfield in jetpack compose. I want to use multiple time so I make a function and use it. when I am passing start padding it decreases the width of other one. Can someone help me on this, where i am wrong here.

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

repeat(2){
       val value =  if (it == 1){
            21.dp
        }else {
            15.dp
        }
        var textFieldValue by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
            mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
        }
        TextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            singleLine = true,
            onValueChange = {
                if (it.text.length <= 4) {
                    textFieldValue = it
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(55.dp)
                .width(88.dp)
                .padding(start = value),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = OffWhite,
                focusedIndicatorColor = TealLight,
                cursorColor = TealLight
            ),
            textStyle = RegularSlate20
        )
    }

  }
```

It look like this

[image]

why my **2nd** textfield is not **88.dp**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the modifiers is important.

You have to use:

```
TextField(
    //....
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(55.dp)
        .padding(start = value) //apply the padding before the width modifier
        .width(88.dp)
 )
```

[image]

Comment: where should I learn order of modifier ?

Comment: @vivekmodi https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#order-modifier-matters

Comment: I really appreciate it.